# capitalize first letter of a sentence in div using css which contains span tag inside

Tags: html, css

I need to capitalize first letter of a sentence which is in div using CSS.
That `div` contains `span` too.
When the span tag is a `first child` of a `div`, `:first-letter` not working.

```css
.sk_tabAlertDes {
  text-transform: lowercase;
}

.sk_tabAlertDes:first-letter {
  text-transform: uppercase !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="sk_tabAlertDesId" class="sk_tabAlertDes errorDesWOH" tabindex="0">
  <span aria-label="Popup Displayed"></span> capitalize first letter of sentence - Span at beginning
</div>

<div id="sk_tabAlertDesId" class="sk_tabAlertDes errorDesWOH" tabindex="0">
  capitalize first letter of sentence - No Span
</div>

<div id="sk_tabAlertDesId" class="sk_tabAlertDes errorDesWOH" tabindex="0">
  capitalize first letter of sentence - Span at end
  <span aria-label="Popup Displayed"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: add `sk_tabAlertDes` on span ?

Comment: @guradio sk_tabAlertDes is just a class name not used

Comment: You have tagged JQuery, but you want answer in CSS? Any specific reason for having answer only in CSS??

Comment: Yes I have restriction, i need to use only css

Comment: So don't tag jQuery then...

Comment: Ok I will correct it. Can you please give solution

Comment: @ Temani Afif, Rory McCrossan Why the query is marked as Duplicate.